# How do I hide all the tab headers of TTabControl in FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tabcontrol

In `FMX.TTabControl`, `TabItem.Visible` makes the whole tab invisible.  And selecting it displays nothing. I know I could make it visible at that point.

How can I hide all the tab headers instead ?

Comment: Do you want to do this at design-time or run-time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [`TabControl.TabPosition`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.TabControl.TTabControl.TabPosition) to `None`

From [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.TabControl.TTabPosition):

> None
>
> The tabs are rendered as small dots on top of the TTabControl
> component, in a lower-down centered position visible **only** at
> design-time. They can be used to switch and display the active tab.
> The small dots are **not visible** at run-time.

Comment: Nice, concise answer, +1.

Comment: I looked at all the properties and methods of Items and Control, but why would I look at TabPosition.  :-)